# How to use html elements in if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make if statement that checks something like:

> If the button clicked and the number of page is equal to 1 it should should alert something

Here is my code:

```html
<button id="last-page" onclick="getNum()">last page</button>
<script>
  function getNum() {
    var numPage = document.getElementById("page-num").value;

    if (numPage === 1) {
      console.log("matches");
    } else {
      console.log("doesn't match");
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="page-num">1</div>
```

But it doesn't match

Why?

Comment: Where's the element with the ID of `page-num`?

Comment: Also, `===` checks for truth, not for a number value. You may want to stick with `==`

Comment: @WesFoster `===` is called strict equality. I don't know what "checks for truth" means, but input values are always strings, so using strict equality on a number literal will always return `false`.

Comment: "2" == 2? Wha's mean?

Comment: Hey King, you could turn this into a Stack Snippet (there is an editor button for it), so we can all run this right here in your question, which makes it easier to reproduce the issue.

Comment: missing code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues going on here:

- You use strict equality `===` where you attempt to compare a string and a number
- You attempt to access `.value` on a non-input element, so `numPage` is `undefined`

Solution:

```html
<button id="last-page" onclick="getNum()">last page</button>
<script>
  function getNum() {
    var numPage = document.getElementById("page-num").textContent;

    if (numPage == 1) {
      console.log("matches");
    } else {
      console.log("doesn't match");
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="page-num">1</div>
```